# access local server from other networks

Tags: networking

I created a localhost server using servlets.

I want to know how to access from other networks(other ip addresses).

what to do for that?

any answers will be helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use public ip address,instead of local ip address to access over the networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by giving **IP address** of your machine in your application url in place of **localhost** while accessing it from another machine in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your ip address instead of localhost.and also need to configure firewall.The firewall can be configured by: choosing the Windows Firewall from the Control Panel, then click on Exceptions -> Add Port and enter name and number: your server, port and leave transport protocol as TCP.

e.g,

```
http://10.4.0.198:8080/project
```